# How to validate files with required in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I have file upload module. Below is my html code.

```
<input type="file"  file-modelsr="myFileID" name="fileupld" valid-files required />
```

On submitting form I am trying to get something like this below.

```
console.log(form2.fileupld.$valid);
```

This always gives me undefined. How can i check file has been uploaded or not on submitting the form?

I have used below directive.

```
myapp.directive('validFiles', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            //change event is fired when file is selected
            el.bind('change', function () {
                debugger;
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
                    ngModel.$render();
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

I used below directive to upload files.

```
myapp.directive('fileModelsr', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModelsr);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I apply required file validation in AngularJS?

Comment: You cannot use angular form validations on file upload. You have to write custom validations by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. i have written valid-files directive. How can i make use of this directive?

Comment: You have to check if your file-modelsr contains a value or not in your directive to validate it.

Comment: How can i check if file-modelsr contains some value?    console.log($scope.myFileID); gives me undefined.

Comment: var model = $parse(attrs.file-modelsr ); inside your link and debug the code and see how to add and what kind of validations you want

Comment: Actually in my directive ngModel is there. But in my input type i have not added any model. So do i need to change my directive? instead of ngModel what should i pass?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151676/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-vivz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `fileModel` directive to the following and get rid of `validFiles` directive. Check if your `fileModelsr` has any value or not and validate based on this.

**JS**:

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', '$rootScope', function($parse, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModelsr);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    if (element[0].files[0]) {
                        $rootScope.fileUploaded = true;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="file" file-modelsr="myFileID" name="fileupld" required />
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!fileUploaded" ng-click="uploadFile()">Submit</button>
```