# bind data to angular.js controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind file input type data to the angular.js controller but after submit the data is undefined.

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control upload " ng-model="image" value="upload">
             <input type="submit" ng-click="uploadimage()" value="upload" class="btn btn-default">
```

angular js controller is

```
//upload image
$scope.uploadimage = function() {
    console.log($scope.image);
}
```

Comment: console.log($scope.image);

Comment: i tried $scope.image too but not working

Comment: please provide more code, at least html and angular module with definition and controllers

Comment: ng-model won't work with input type file, you have to write a custom directive for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628050/how-to-validate-files-with-required-in-angularjs/45628659#45628659 .  Or you can use any plugin for this.

Answer (score 1):

The file input type is missing from the ng-model directive, so you need to install a package for file uploads with AngularJS.